# String pattern find character

Tags: c#

My text file is formatted like such;

```
ID: 300000000 NAME: 3rd: Ellin Forest: Altaire Camp
ID: 300000100 NAME: 3rd: Altaire Camp: Small Forest
ID: 687000000 NAME: Gacha_GL: Gacha: Gachapon
ID: 682000000 NAME: HalloweenGL: Phantom Forest: Haunted House
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include the buffer part in your regex:

```
ID: (?<id>\d*) NAME: (?<buffer>.*?:) (?<name>.*)
```

Comment: ".*" is greedy! Use ".*?" instead for the buffer part, otherwise buffer will match until the last colon.

Answer (score 1):

```
string name =  match.Groups["name"].Value; // "Gacha_GL: Gacha: Gachapon";
string correctName = String.Join(": ", name.Split(new[]{": "}, StringSplitOptions.None).Skip(1).ToArray());
```

Not regex, but does the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can amend your `Regex` to get this ouput directly via

```
string pattern = @"ID: (?<id>\d*) NAME:(?<prename>.*?:)(?<name>.*)";
```

But I am not sure whether you *needed* to use the origonal `Regex`, in which case you can do this without breaking you existing `Regex` as follows

```
void PopulateWith(string rawText)
{
    string pattern = @"ID: (?<id>\d*) NAME: (?<name>.*)";
    foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(rawText, pattern))
    {
        int id = int.Parse(match.Groups["id"].Value);
        string name = match.Groups["name"].Value;
        name = String.Join(": ", 
            name.Split(new[]{": "}, StringSplitOptions.None).Skip(1).ToArray());
    }
}
```

These both produce output as required:

> Gacha: Gachapon

I hope this helps.